# Hibernate does not create my tables

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

I'm having a weird problem using Spring and Hibernate. I started using Hibernate using this in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

It worked fine, and Hibernate successfully created the tables needed in the database.
Now I'm using Spring and my bean used for hibernate in applicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>domain/Entity.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>domain/Service.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>domain/User.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>domain/Arcos.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I had to drop the tables created by Hibernate at some point but Spring doesn't create them. I tried with `create-drop` instead of `create` (just in case someone asks). My DB Schema changed since I used Hibernate and I'm using a lot of `getBeans("...");` in my code so it kind of bother me to reuse my Hibernate-only version just to create the tables. I also could create the table by hand, but what would be the point of using these frameworks?

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong somewhere, but I cannot find it. The console prompt an error saying there is no table named "*the name of the table*", so it connects to the DB successfully.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Did you try enabling show-sql  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> - It could help you .

Comment: IMHO using ddl can give unexpected results when refactoring your code... Consider managing your ddl via another mechanism, such as Liquibase.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`hibernate.hbm2dll.auto` --> `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

DLL = Dynamic Link Library

DDL = Data Definition Language

Comment: Oops indeed! Thanks for pointing that out it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your code

```
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

in the solution